# LinuxMint, unable to set swap partitions to equal priority

Tags: linux, swap, fstab

I only recently realised that you can specify multiple swap partition, spreading them across drives. Well that's great for me as my desktop system often uses swap space and I have three different drives spread across two controllers. One of which is a dedicated raid5.If your curious, it's a retired server. :)

If you set them to the same priority it will "round-robin" them, or spread the workload between them. At least as I understand it.

Nonetheless, I can't seem to get both swap partitions to the same priority. Here is my fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
/dev/sda1       /               ext4    errors=remount-ro,user_xattr 0       1
/dev/sdb1       none            swap    sw pri=1        0       0
/dev/sda3       none            swap    sw pri=1        0       0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

I'm using `swapoff -a` and `swapon -a` to turn off then back on the swap files. When I use `swapon -s` I get:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sdb1               partition   5855656 1408        -1
/dev/sda3               partition   2093052 0           -2
```

Any ideas why it's not setting the priority the same?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `swapon -p 1` in order to do the changes without the `fstab` file, after it is working with that you change the `fstab`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `options` field in fstab is ***comma***-delimited (note every other (non-swap) line). You have spaces.
Fix that and it should work as intended.

[image: Red freehand circles!]

Comment: after you change the fstab file, you shouldn't reboot your computer, just do `swapon -a`.

Comment: Ah that worked great. I just need another pair of eyes to look at it. Thank you.